# Generate large feed in streaming fashion

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I should implemented to OData service that will be able generate feed in streaming fashion 
i.e. - client should start read first entries of the feed when service still generate next entries.

Is such behavior possible with WCF Data Services ?

For now I cannot do such behavior - service firstly generate entire feed in buffer and only then start 
transfer it to client but such behavior doesn't fit for me due to the is too large for generating in buffer 
it doesn't contain BLOB properties just very many rows so implementation of IDataServiceMetadataProvider won't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was be able to  resolve this problem just by allowing WCF streaming - specifing transferMode="Streamed":

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
  <services>
    <service name="ODataDemo.OdataDemoDataService">
      <endpoint bindingConfiguration="msgSize" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>       
      <binding name="msgSize" transferMode="Streamed" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible. WCF services (as well as WCF Data Services) provides streaming but the streaming support is not based on concurrent writing and reading on both ends of communication. Streaming for example works well if you have a file on disk and you pass its stream to WCF channel for sending.

The problem is the way how WCF is architected. You will not get transport stream in your service operation and that is the whole source of the problem. You will have to start some new stream or open another existing stream and only after you return this stream from an operation it will be passed to underlaying WCF infrastructure and copied to a transport stream. But this means that the stream must be prepared (contain all data) prior to returning from your service operation.

I tried to build service where the stream would be continuously filled from another thread after returning from an operation but it didn't work at all.